# Zero earnings from AdMob interstitials

Tags: admob, banner, interstitial

I'm used to the fact that banner clicks in AdMob give low earnings, but interstitials are much higher. So I'm surprised to see that some interstitial clicks from the US give 0.00. Is it normal?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe, you say about social ads. Yes, it doesn't bring money.